# Crystal Report - List of Values Running Total Fields?

Tags: crystal-reports-2013

I'm pretty new to Crystal Reports. I would like to make a formula, I'm assuming it will be a Running Total Field, to list all the values (excluding null). How would I go about this? Here's my situation to clarify.  I have a RFI Reference column (String), but a lot of the rows are suppressed due to duplicate data. However, I would like to list all the RFI Reference that appear on the suppressed rows, excluding the Nulls. It will need to reset, after some conditions, that's why I'm assuming it will be a Running Total Field. Just not sure what I should be using to make this happen. Thanks in advance. 
(V 14.1)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Blackbaud's KB. It's not exactly what I was looking for but I made it work.  It was really helpful unlike the 2 trolls giving me negative on rep for asking a question... way to build the community. Anyway, with some formatting I made it work for me.

Create the following three formulas in the Crystal Report:

Formula 1: this formula concatenates each value into one string. Place in Details section and suppress the field.
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar ConCat;
If ConCat = "" then ConCat := {Field_Name} else if not({Field_Name} in ConCat) then ConCat := ConCat + ", " + {Field_Name}

Formula 2: this formula will display the final value. Place in Group Footer section.
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar ConCat;

Formula 3: this formula will reset the variable for the next record. Place in Group Header to remove previous record's value.
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar ConCat := ""